# Intermittent freezing on a Macbook Pro 7,1

Tags: macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my MacBook Pro 7, 1. I used to have 11.10 on it. I've encountered a problem were I can boot up and the login screen works flawlessly. When I attempt to log into my account I set up during install it would only show the default wallpaper and the mouse was frozen.

In other words it was logging on but froze up. Is what it seems like. When I rebooted I attempted to log into the guest account. I was able to log in and it seemed everything worked so I tried to update everything figuring it may be the problem.

After updating and restarting as prompted I tried to login to my account. It still froze up but this time showing "glitched up" (you can see the dock and status bar but they don't look like they should) and still freezes.

This is all happening on the guest account to. I was unable to find a similar article on the Internet therefore I am asking; Any thoughts Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to a known bug when the proprietary Nvidia driver is installed.
They forgot to add linux-headers-generic as a dependency for installing the nvidia driver.

Try to get into a virtual terminal, I don't have a MAC, but on the PC you get to one by using CTRL+ALT+F1 .

Once you get there, log in, get root privileges  (sudo -i),  and do

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Once that's done, try to reinstall the nvidia driver.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Reboot and hopefully it should work then for you.

Comment: ctrl-alt-fn-f1, I believe, but I don't have a mac to try it on.